# phantomjs - page.onError - trace is always an empty object?

Tags: phantomjs

In the documentation of **phantomjs** they say the following:

***Error Handling**
To easily catch an error occured in a web page, whether it is a syntax error or other thrown exception, an onError handler for the WebPage object has been added. An example on such a handler is:*

```
page.onError = function (msg, trace) {
    console.log(msg);
    trace.forEach(function(item) {
        console.log('  ', item.file, ':', item.line);
    })
}
```

*Now if the page opens a site with some JavaScript exceptions, a detailed information (including the stack trace) will be printed out.*

Well, I have created a few 'broken' pages (pages where the javascript causes an exception) and I get 
the error that gets thrown but nothing in the trace

Can somebody help ?

Here is an example of a case I had:

html:

```
<!docType>
<html><head></head>
<body>
<script src='broken.js'></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

script: broken.js

```
1. // this script is broken at line 5.
2. // 
3. var i=20;
4. 
5. i = somethingThatDontExist
6. 
7. // we will never be here...
8.
```

Comment: Can you present a reproduceable test case?

Comment: @AriyaHidayat Yes, sure. I have added into my query. Many thanks for stepping in.

Comment: @Zo72 Did you checked my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably missed something in your test settings but everything works fine. You maybe forgot that phantomJS calls are asynchronous.

Here is my test settings:

**test.html**

```
<!docType>
<html><head></head>
  <body>
    <script src='broken.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**broken.js**

```
var i = 20;
i = somethingThatDontExist;
```

**testError.js**

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.onError = function (msg, trace) {
  console.log(msg);
  trace.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(' ', item.file, ':', item.line);
  })
}
page.open('test.html',function(){phantom.exit()});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but still an issue (I ran into this recently).  The OP was probably using an older version.

A few things to check...

**1) The API for `console.log` has changed between phantomjs 2.1.1 and 2.5.0.  In 2.5.0 `console.log` only prints the first argument (in 2.1.1 it would print all).**

To be safe try building a string first and logging that as a single argument just to make sure this isn't just a logging issue.  ie `console.log(concatenatedString)` not `console.log(var1, var2, var3,...)`

Use `JSON.stringify(object)` if you want to concatenate your objects and arrays.

**2) In my experience phantomjs is inconsistent about how it captures errors in the page context.**

For instance if (in the page) a javascript catchblock does a `console.log('message', error)`, the phantomjs `page.onConsoleMessage` callback will get a string for the message and a string "[object Object]"...so any data about the error contained within that object is lost between the page context and phantomjs.

(`console.error` might have different behaviour than `console.log`, but I didn't test it.)

**3) `page.onError` is broken in phantomjs 2.5.0 at the moment.  It never gets called, instead errors show up in `page.onConsoleMessage` but miss the error object (see #2).**

Use phantomjs 2.1.1 for now if you really need to know if there is a javascript error on page.

See the below bug for repro code that illustrates the differences between 2.1.1 and 2.5.0 when it comes to `page.onError`, `page.onResourceError` and `page.onConsoleMessage`.

https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/14776